# MFC mouse move/leave, hover on button

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to change background button when mouse move or mouse leave or click on button. I write my app in MFC.
Please help with demo/sample.

Answer (score 1):

How to track mouse movements? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903892/detect-when-mouse-leaves-my-app)

How to change the bitmaps of the MFC buttons? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047470/how-to-add-bitmap-image-to-buttons-in-mfc)

Comment: Can you give me full source demo?

Comment: @hung nguyen how much will you pay me?

Comment: @James Allan: I am student, please help me, thank so much!!!

Comment: @hung nguyen you spelt "do all my work for me" wrong